# Ability to set users free/busy in MS Exchange Server

Tags: exchange-server

We are trying to integrate our app with MS Exchange. One of possible features of that integration is to let other apps know if our app user currently performing some important work, so other users should see him as busy.
All APIs I found allow to get user free/busy status, but not set. Is there public api for a writing side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The free/busy time option on Microsoft Exchange is generated from the Outlook/Exchange Calendar entries from the users. These infos are fetched from the users calendar by the Availability service as written by Microsoft [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb232134(v=exchg.150).aspx). So if you wish to "SET" something, you need to create an calendar entry for the user. If you try to add something to the backend environment which is managed by Microsoft Exchange you might cause issues for the users as they do not see that in there calendars. That is also the reason why you are unable to find a "free/busy time writing API". So please create a calendar entry for your purpose and let the MS Exchange Availability service do the rest.

A good starting point to understand the construct is:

- [Availability service in Exchange 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb232134(v=exchg.150).aspx)